# Apple pay in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, stripe-payments, applepayjs

I was implementing apple pay in react native application, and I was having trouble with the payment process. Once the transaction has been successfully completed where will the account go? How to manage the payment token do I have to send this token to stripe or any other merchant? can I manage the amount in the apple account directly?

I am using the react-native-payments npm package for apple pay which has been deprecated already but no other options have been available so far.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is not suitable for this forum. Check Reactiflux Discord, or contact Apple directly about available payment options.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I contacted apple and got my issue resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Stripe's React Native SDK does support Apple/Google Pay out of the box. Is there a specific reason behind choosing `react-native-payments` package over the official SDK?

Stripe also has a pretty good guide for this
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment

There are specific [sections](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet#react-native-apple-pay) to enable wallets for your React Native app.

Comment: Actually client wanted to save some money as stripe charges a good amount of fees although it’s not a good practice to use any third party package for payments. 

So i found hyper pay sdk for apple pay and its charges are better than stripe.

Comment: That's good to know. Although having a stingy client is never fun. Been there, done that.